# Redirect static IP to domain

Tags: asp.net, redirect, static, static-ip-address

I want to redirect my static IP to my domain.if entered IP its redirect to domain and show domain on URL. My web site is http://www.ramadoor.co and ip is : 87.247.179.84 .its on IIS and ASP.NET webform.Tanks

Comment: You need to configure in whre you purchase your doamin.

Comment: its configured with my web,but I want to redirect it.If typed 87.247.179.84 redirect to my domain.now its load my site but shows IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it helps you.

If the IP is assigned properly in the site binding and you're not using a host header then all you need to do is ensure that the domain name is registered and the A Record (host record) in DNS is pointing to the IP of the site.

It sounds like either DNS is not configured properly or the IIS site bindings are not configured properly or within your application there is some type of redirect occurring.

Add a binding to a site IIS 7
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx

Configure a Host Header for a Web Site (IIS 7)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx

## Copied from [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1194060.aspx?Display%20domain%20name%20instead%20of%20IP)